# Ansible: Run modules on a target host in a virtual enviroment

Tags: ansible, openstack

I want to run the [os_server](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/os_server_module.html) module on a target host which has a virtual enviroment where openstacksdk is installed. If I try to run the script as shown below it results in a error "conflicting action statements: virtualenv, os_server". How can I specify a virtual enviroment correctly so that ansible uses it? I don't want to install openstacksdk globally and just use the venv.

```
- name: Create Server
  virtualenv: "/home/user/otc2/bin/activate"
  os_server:
    state: present
    auto_ip: false
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would set the [`ansible_python_interpreter` hostvar](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html) for that host to point to the python binary inside the virtualenv on the remote machine, which appears to be `/home/user/otc2/bin/python` based on your posted snippet

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This solved the problem really quick and easy.
Just for clarification to all the others: You can set the ansible_python_interpreter var inside a inventory list if you want. Also it would work too as a global variable.